# Posting image using vb.net to pinterest

Tags: vb.net, pinterest

Currently i'm trying to post an image from an vb.net website to pinterest.
I got the key and access token trough the documented way.
nut now i'm trying to send the data to the server to create a pin but i get an 500 internal server error. is there something wrong with my request that caused it or is it all on their side.

```
Public Function SendMessage(url As String, json As String)
    Try
        Dim client As New RestClient(url)
        Dim request As New RestRequest(Method.POST)
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
        request.AddBody(json)
        dim response = client.Execute(request)
        Return response
    Catch ex As exception
        Status = ex
        Return Nothing
    End Try 
End Function
```

The used URL https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/?access_token={mytoken}&fields=board%2Cnote%2Cimage%2Clink

and the json message

```
{
"board": "{board}",
"note": "test pin2",
"link": "{hyperlink}",
"image_url": "{image url}"
}
```

Response

```
{
"message": "'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'",
"type": "http"
}
status: "Internal Server Error"
```

I hope someone can point out wat i'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I notice you've listed all the fields in the url but you've used `image` instead of `image_url`

Comment: Unfortunately that is the only option but the URL resembles the return values. and there are multiple possibilities 1. image 2. image_url 3. image_base64